# Performance issues for HTML/CSS/JS Metaballs under Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working on a metaball animation for the website of our design studio and I have an issue with the performance of the animation. The full code is below and here's the link to my current CodePen - https://codepen.io/malosch/pen/vardvp.

It's performing fine (i.e. smooth) with Google Chrome but Firefox is displaying everything choppy and Safari is not running the animation at all. I did some testing and the culprit seems to be the blurring inside the *.dot* class in the CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <p class="title"> Transforming Ideas into Realities</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Other website content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.stage {
  position: relative;
  padding: 100px;
  background: #fff;

  -webkit-filter: contrast(50);
  -moz-filter: contrast(50);
  -ms-filter: contrast(50);
  -o-filter: contrast(50);
  filter: contrast(50);

  border: 5px solid black;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 82px;
}

.dot { 
  position: absolute;

  z-index: -1;

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius:50%;

  -moz-filter: blur(25%);
  -ms-filter: blur(25%);
  -o-filter: blur(25%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
  filter: blur(25px);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var dots = $('.dot').toArray();

  for(var i=0; i < dots.length; i++){
    var myDot = dots[i];
    animateDiv(myDot);
  }
});

function animateDiv(myClass){
  var newPos = makeNewPosition();
  var duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 2000;

  $(myClass).animate({ left: newPos[0], top: newPos[1] }, duration, function(){
    animateDiv(myClass);
  });
};

function makeNewPosition(){
  var w = $('.stage').width() - $('.dot').width();
  var h = $('.stage').height() - $('.dot').height();

  var xOffset = 0;
  var yOffset = 100;

  var newX = Math.floor(Math.random() * w + xOffset);
  var newY = Math.floor(Math.random() * h + yOffset);

  return [newX,newY];
};
```

Do you guys know/have any tips or pointers as to why Firefox and Safari dislike the blur filter? And is there anything I can do to run the animation smooth cross-browser (excluding IE)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: css filters, especially blurring, are very expensive to compute. Rather than calculating new positions and animating elements with js, you should look at an approach like this https://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/sEbFz. It runs quite nicely on Safari and Firefox and requires no js. You should create the animation effect with keyframes and set it to loop. Make the keyframes a bit more complex to somewhat hide the looping behavior. I believe this is your best option.

Comment: Thanks, @Geuis. I'll have a closer look at the example you shared and give it a try using keyframes on loop. Will report back when I'm done.